# Promise pending, promisestatus=resolved?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch

I am trying to access the results (here it is the 'body') of the fetch but keep getting  this :

Promise {< pending >}
**proto**
:
Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]
:
"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]
:
Array(100)

it says resolved but isnt just giving me the array I want.

here is my code

```
    let Categories =  fetch('http://localhost:3001/categories?' )
                 .then((response) => {
                  var data = response.json();

                 return data;


               }).then((body) => {
                    console.log("fetching categories...")
                    console.log(body.categories)

                 return body.categories
               })


    console.log(Categories)
    export default Categories
```

the above result comes from the console.log(Categories)

Comment: Sounds like you [misunderstand the console output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23392111/1048572). It shows "resolved" only when you click it, which is after the request succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Categories` is still a Promise. You have to call `.then` on it where you import it and you will receive your body.categories in the parameter.

EDIT:
Additional info from comments (I can't format it nicely there).

It's async so it can't go to initialState of a Redux store. You should:

- make an action creator that fetches this data
- when the data is fetched dispatch an action with this data, e.g:

  `{ type: 'CATEGORIES_LOAD', data: data }`
- make a reducer which updates this store

And execute this action creator when your component mounts, e.g. componentWillMount if you also use React.

Comment: Should have been more specific...  I am trying to import it to be in my redux store.  How would I do it with that?

Comment: Why would you want to import the result of an API call in redux store

Comment: @DavidSS
It's async so it can't go to initialState. You should:

- make an action creator that fetches this data

- when the data is fetched dispatch an action with this data, e.g:

```
{ type: 'CATEGORIES_LOAD', data: data }
```
- make a reducer which updates this store

And execute this action creator when your component mounts, e.g. componentWillMount if you also use React.

Comment: I've edited my answer because format here doesn't work.
If you don't know how to dispatch async actions look for redux-thunk or redux-saga.